# Spyder traceback (most recent call last) error when attempting to launch from Anaconda navigator after installing Spark

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, traceback

Spyder has launched for me in the past but has been throwing this error after I installed Spark.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled python/Anaconda/and Spyder, have restarted my computer, and have tried out a few command prompt lines in StackOverflow (such as ones that uninstall/reinstall Spyder). I have also updated the Anaconda navigator.

The error is as follows. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 113, in main
from spyder.config.manager import CONF
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\manager.py", line 636, in 
CONF = ConfigurationManager()
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\manager.py", line 71, in __init__
self._user_config = MultiUserConfig(
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 786, in __init__
self._configs_map[name] = config_class(**new_kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 212, in __init__
self._load_from_ini(previous_fpath)
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 333, in _load_from_ini
self.read(fpath, encoding='utf-8')
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\configparser.py", line 697, in read
self._read(fp, filename)
File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaReinstall\lib\configparser.py", line 1116, in _read
raise e
configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\.spyder-py3\\config\\transient.ini'enter code here
[line 97]: ".py']\n"
```

The file with the error in it (transient) is as follows:

```
[main]
completion/size = (300, 180)
window/position = (-9, -9)
window/prefs_dialog_size = (1050, 530)
window/size = (1920, 1001)
version = 63.0.0
current_version = 4.2.5
historylog_filename = C:\Users\lgp35\.spyder-py3\history.log
spyder_pythonpath = ['C:\\gurobi950-new\\win64', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0']
window/state = 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
last_visible_toolbars = ['file_toolbar', 'run_toolbar', 'debug_toolbar', 'main_toolbar', 'Current working directory']

[main_interpreter]
custom_interpreters_list = ['C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe']
custom_interpreter = C:\Users\lgp35\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
executable = C:\Users\lgp35\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe

[onlinehelp]
zoom_factor = 0.8

[project_explorer]
max_recent_projects = 10
recent_projects = []
current_project_path = None
scrollbar_position = (0, 0)
expanded_state = None

[quick_layouts]
place_holder = 
names = ['Matlab layout', 'Rstudio layout', 'Vertical split', 'Horizontal split']
order = ['Matlab layout', 'Rstudio layout', 'Vertical split', 'Horizontal split']
active = ['Matlab layout', 'Rstudio layout', 'Vertical split', 'Horizontal split']
layout_0/size = (640, 480)
layout_0/prefs_dialog_size = (1050, 530)
layout_0/is_maximized = True
layout_0/is_fullscreen = False
layout_0/position = (631, 237)
layout_0/state = None
layout_0/statusbar = True
layout_1/size = (640, 480)
layout_1/prefs_dialog_size = (1050, 530)
layout_1/is_maximized = True
layout_1/is_fullscreen = False
layout_1/position = (631, 237)
layout_1/state = None
layout_1/statusbar = True
layout_2/size = (640, 480)
layout_2/prefs_dialog_size = (1050, 530)
layout_2/is_maximized = True
layout_2/is_fullscreen = False
layout_2/position = (631, 237)
layout_2/state = None
layout_2/statusbar = True
layout_3/size = (640, 480)
layout_3/prefs_dialog_size = (1050, 530)
layout_3/is_maximized = True
layout_3/is_fullscreen = False
layout_3/position = (631, 237)
layout_3/state = None
layout_3/statusbar = True
layout_default/size = (640, 480)
layout_default/prefs_dialog_size = (1050, 530)
layout_default/is_maximized = True
layout_default/is_fullscreen = False
layout_default/position = (631, 237)
layout_default/state = None
layout_default/statusbar = True

[appearance]
windows_style = windowsvista

[workingdir]
console/fixed_directory = 
startup/fixed_directory = C:\Users\lgp35\OneDrive\Desktop\Wilke

[outline_explorer]
expanded_state = {6619655339172676187: True, -5870714686722897003: True, -3287618310915648216: False, 7179539718179923746: False, -3922813285135763362: False, -949799931923314090: False, -4590830462528342624: False, -8761696352674379884: True, 6057805215997114419: False, 303167271063810693: False, 1961776347392259777: False, 2019671237437652774: False, 7538465358293634210: False, 296300372827570621: False, -8696255247109053465: False, -5461463049454827109: False, 2676938966763078969: False, -6938666991721339614: False, -7186815617839420170: False, 2407509920692351087: False, 6320716940273758968: False, -3326984708763332812: False, -3069346561960451413: False, 595427275764705991: False, 3130298443478084597: False, 3885502619072052669: False, 5671860636290307661: False, -7572666756581373626: False, -1481695455214279801: False, -794044643856266835: False, 4560007193278669634: False, 3051169483710397096: False, 7092620404617490210: False, -8368100190470485923: False, 4665201080009147335: False, -3023943122849557514: False, 8817248686606909854: False, -6260782265693089995: False, -4629428213613907303: False, -7624680801646661272: False, -5417313392231161577: False}
scrollbar_position = (0, 0)

[editor]
splitter_state = 000000ff00000001000000010000038901ffffffff010000000100
recent_files = ['C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\RatingCounter.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\Friends-By-Age.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\arec-f.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\MostPopularSuperhero.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\MovieSimilarities.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\Assignment3Individual.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\arec-f-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\Min-Temperatures.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\Max-Temperatures.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\WordFrequency.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\MostPopularMovie.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\ml-100k\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\M2MapReduce.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Heuristic Algorithms\\Assignment1\\enumerate-knapsack-template.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Heuristic Algorithms\\Assignment1\\knapsack-template.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment2\\binpack-template-section2.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Heuristic Algorithms\\Assignment2\\binpack-template-sectiofilenamesfilenames = ['C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\MostPopularSuperhero.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\MovieSimilarities.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\Assignment3Individual.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\arec-f.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\Friends-By-Age.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\RatingCounter.py']
bookmarks = {}
layout_settings = {'hexstate': '000000ff00000001000000010000046400ffffffff010000000100', 'sizes': [1124], 'splitsettings': [(False, 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\Assignment3Individual.py', [8, 16, 19, 64, 1, 1, 1])]}

[explorer]
file_associations = {}

[run]
breakpoints = {}
configurations = [('C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\json_scrapeFINALVERSION.py', {'args/enabled': False, 'args': '', 'workdir/enabled': None, 'workdir': None, 'current': True, 'systerm': False, 'interact': False, 'post_mortem': False, 'python_args/enabled': False, 'python_args': '', 'clear_namespace': False, 'console_namespace': False, 'file_dir': True, 'cw_dir': False, 'fixed_dir': False, 'dir': ''})]
defaultconfiguration = {}
default/wdir/fixed_directory = C:\Users\lgp35\OneDrive\Desktop\Wilke

[pylint]
history_filenames = ['C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\Assignment3Individual.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\arec-f.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\Friends-By-Age.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\MovieSimilarities.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\RatingCounter.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\MostPopularSuperhero.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\Assignment3.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\arec-f-retyped.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M3\\buad5132-m3-files\\PythonFiles\\arec-f-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\Min-Temperatures.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\Max-Temperatures.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\MostPopularMovie.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\WordFrequency.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\buad5132-m2-files\\PythonFiles\\ml-100k\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\M2MapReduce.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Summer_2022\\Online Courses\\ML2\\M2\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\M2MapReduce-1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Heuristic Algorithms\\Assignment1\\knapsack-template.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment3\\Recursive_Updated.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment1\\Knapsack_Recursion.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment1\\knapsack-example-post (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Heuristic Algorithms\\Assignment1\\enumerate-knapsack-template.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment2\\binpack-template-section2.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment2\\binpack-template (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment1\\Knapsack_assignment_extension.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\AssignmentExtensions\\HA\\Assignment2\\BinPackingBestFit.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Heuristic Algorithms\\Assignment2\\binpack-template-section2.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\binpack-template (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Big Data\\Lab2\\MRProgram.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Big Data\\Lab2\\mr_count_lab2_problem (2).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Big Data\\Lab2\\MRProgramProblem3.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Big Data\\Lab2\\MRProgramProblem1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Big Data\\Lab2\\MRProgramProblem2.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Big Data\\Lab2\\MRProgramFinal.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Files for final project\\dataprocess.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Files for final project\\etf_subset.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Files for final project\\Model1.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Files for final project\\BIL.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Artificial Intelligence\\FinalProject\\FinalProject.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras pretrained word embeddings glove new words (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Artificial Intelligence\\FinalProject.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras smaller longer LSTM network to learn sequences of characters.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras Longer LSTM network to learn sequences of characters.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras Larger LSTM network to learn sequences of characters.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras Larger LSTM network to write sequences of characters.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras LSTM network to write sequences of characters(1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - learn for LSTM word-by-word K m2.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - learn for LSTM word-by-word K m3.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - LSTM - word-by-word - write(1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras -  LSTM - word-by-word - Process text.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras pretrained word embeddings glove.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - MLM - Learning and embedding.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\keras - word embedding training.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras pretrained word embeddings glove - new text.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras Bidirectional LSTM Simple IMDB (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras GRU Simple IMDB.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras LSTM Simple IMDB.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras pretrained word embeddings glove new words.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras SimpleRNN Simple IMDB.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras LSTM network to learn sequences of characters(1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - Boston.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\NN - template.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Artificial Intelligence\\Resources\\Keras - Mnist - Covnet.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MSBA_Spring_2022\\Artificial Intelligence\\Resources\\Keras Convnet Example.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\KERAS.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Capacity_layers and nodes.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Capacity_layers.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Capacity_nodes.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - Housing - Data PreProcessing.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - Boston - Class(1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\Keras - Boston - Class.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Wilke\\projecttahirfinal.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Wilke\\ProjectTahirDraft.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Wilke\\ProjectCodeDraft12.9.21912PM.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Wilke\\ProjectCodeDraft12.9.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\ProjectCodeDraft.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Wilke\\ProjectCodeDraft.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\mod18-original (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\mod18-final (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Wilke\\ProblemSet2FINAL.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\Downloads\\mod18-cont (1).py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Wilke\\tahirfinal.py', 'C:\\Users\\lgp35\\.spyder-py3\\te
.py']
```

Comment: Hello @lasya and welcome to StackOverflow! From the error message it seems that your config contains "parsing errors". Can you edit your post to include the contents of your config file `C:\Users\lgp35\.spyder-py3\config\transient.ini` (which has errors), or at least line 97 (the erroring line)?

Comment: @David, thank you so much for your help. I will edit my post to include it.

Comment: Not sure but seems like the line with the error is related with the last path (`C:\\Users\\lgp35\\.spyder-py3\\te.py`) in `history_filenames` for the `Pylint` section. Could you try to remove it? If that doesn't help. You can try to reset the Spyder config by running from an Anaconda prompt with the env Spyder is installed activated `spyder --reset` (note that running this will erase all you Spyder preferences)

Comment: @DanielAlthviz, thank you for your help- that worked and it's launching now!

Comment: Awesome! Will then put an answer following the comment above

Answer (score 1):

Since seems like the line with the error is related with the last path (`C:\\Users\\lgp35\\.spyder-py3\\te.py`) in `history_filenames` for the `Pylint` section. To prevent the parsing error be sure to remove the bad formatted path. If that doesn't help, you can try to reset the Spyder config by running from an Anaconda prompt with the environment Spyder is installed activated `spyder --reset` (note that running this will erase all you Spyder preferences)